ASE v2 to V3 migration - pre validation REST URL is not working
I am trying to do the ASE V2 to V3 migration using Azure CLI commands. I am following the Microsoft documentation.
I am able to complete below steps:

Get your App Service Environment ID - Completed

Validate that migration is supported - I have encountered an error. I have executed the below Azure CLI command in DevOps pipeline.
az rest --method post --uri "${ASE_ID}/migrate?api-version=2021-02-01&phase=validation"

Its is throwing an error

Error: Not found () No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://dm1.geomaster.azurewebsites.windows.net:444/subscriptions/<subscription_ID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroup_ID>/providers/Microsoft.web/hostingEnvironments/<APP_SERVICE_ENVIRONMENT_NAME>/migrate?api-version=2021-02-01'. Phase is not recognized as internal and external command.



Can someone please look into this issue and provide the suggestions?
FYI, our organization is not supporting to perform this migration using the Azure portal, so we have to go with the Azure CLI option using devops.
